# open webpage using parameter in obiee

Tags: obiee

My requirement is to open a webpage from pivot table of OBIEE

eg:

I have a link called www.abcd.com/id. This id value should come from the another column in the same analysis. whenever I select the id, the link value should change. If I select 123 from dashboard prompt, then link should change to  www.abcd.com/123. This link should appear as it is in the pivot column along with the id I selected,from where i can click and open the webpage

I tried selecting html in a text column and then using the html code as 
 http://abcd.com”>ABCD, but it is not working..

Any suggestion would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking things. It's very straight-forward:

'https://www.google.com/search?q=' || "YourTable"."YourColumn"

And then set the column properties data format to "Treat Text as" and then "HyperText Link". Done.